# Where is my AD-Integrated stub zone data being stored?

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, active-directory

I have an Active-Directory integrated stub zone that appears to be functioning properly (zone data is populated on every DC). It is stored in the DomainDNSZones partition, but I do not see any dnsNode objects in its container. I was previously under the impression that any DNS zones that are domain-scoped would store all of their zone information here, but I see that there must be more to it than that. Where else could the zone data be loaded from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Stub Zone's records are stored in memory only, and are lost when the DNS service is stopped.

The DNS server will, upon starting up, query the zone's `SOA` and `NS` records from the defined list of authoritative servers (it can also be set to add additional received `NS` records to its local list) to store and serve.  It will also serve up any glue `A` or `AAAA` records that are needed, if the authoritative name servers' DNS names are within this same stub zone - these records should be returned as extra data by the authoritative server in response to the `NS` query.

The only records that the Stub Zone which needs to be stored in a persistent way is the list of authoritative servers to query for the `NS` and `SOA` records, to populate the zone.  This is stored in the `dNSProperty` attribute of the zone's object within the `DomainDNSZones` or `ForestDNSZones` partition.

Comment: Thank you very much; that explains a lot. Might I ask where you found this information? I'd love to be able to go straight to the source next time.

Comment: "Find" isn't quite the right word - I came by my information by setting it up in a lab environment and digging.

Comment: Got it. Well, thanks for sharing your hard earned information!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you look in dnsmgmt at the the stub zone which will list all the records (which then should allow you to see their local location)?

Edit: Ah, I didn't read the word container so I assume you used DNS Manager. A Zone DB should be stored in %systemroot%/SYSTEM32/DNS/domain_name.dns.

Comment: That would be for a non-AD integrated zone. AD integrated zones are stored in AD, not the file system of the DNS server.

Comment: Why did you just not write "a zone that stores its zone data in Active Directory. DNS zone files are not needed," then?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Are you asking why I didn't phrase my comment the way you suggest in your comment? If so, then what I stated in my comment is exactly the same idea, stated using different words. Or maybe I'm misunderstanding you completely.

Comment: @Ethabelle: AD integrated zones aren't stored as files, they're inside the AD database (look at the original question).

Comment: @pauska And how is what you said different than what joeqwerty said?

Comment: @Ethabelle It's not, so.. uhm. Come back to the chat, we have a video to cheer you up!

Comment: @pauska Oh, lol. Was just making sure, though knowing they are in the database clears up the 'where'. Lookatthat, answered a question wrong and learnededed something new. Win!